# Are there better ways to overload similar arithmetic operators?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Say I have a rather complex structure:

```
struct Wrapper {
  int value;
};
```

And I can overload operators for the structure:

```
Wrapper operator+(const Wrapper &w1, const Wrapper &w2) {
  Wrapper tmp;
  tmp.value = w1.value + w2.value;
  return tmp;
}
```

It's obvious that I can overload other operators (`-`, `*`, `/` ...) respectively, in similar way. However if we repeat the similar piece of code, it will get complicated and prone to error.

From my experience in C, it might be possible to use macro for this kind of task, but it seems macros are not recommended in C++.

So are there any better ways of overloading more than one operators, one-off, than this?

Comment: [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/operators.htm) can help you reduce the overall number of operators defined yourself

Comment: You can simplify this particular operator to `return w1.value + w2.value;`, if `tmp` has a constructor (or is POD)

Comment: It's quite common to use templates for this... for an example, check Standard Library's implementation of `std::atomic<>` (create `x.cc` containing `#include <atomic>` then invoke your preprocessor/pager, e.g. `g++ -E x.cc | less`).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the metaprogramming C++ abilities are quite limited in scope and this kind of code generation is not possible using templates.

Some macrology for this specific problem is not really bad... for example

```
#define defbinop(op)                                        \
MyValue operator op (const MyValue& a, const MyValue& b) {  \
    return MyValue(a.value op b.value);                     \
}

defbinop(+)
defbinop(-)
defbinop(*)
defbinop(/)
defbinop(<<)
defbinop(>>)
...
```

is more readable and without any serious side effect...

Comment: *"this kind of code generation is not possible using templates"* - in what way are you saying template-based solutions (e.g. [boost operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/utility/operators.htm)) fall short?

Comment: @TonyD: `boost/operators` does a different thing; implementing operators based on other operators on the same class. Here I'm implementing instead class operators based on C++ native operators (or operators defined on **other** classes). Basically one big limitation (of the many) of the C++ template approach is that you cannot pass and manipulate arbitrary syntax parts (like `+`) but only types, constant values or other templates (also with annoying limitations). Not even **full expressions** or **names** can be template arguments...

Comment: that boost::operator guides the addition of operators by detection of existing user-supplied operators doesn't change the larger fact that *it shows how to use templates to effectively mix-in/inject operators*... i.e. it doesn't have to be done with macros.

Comment: @TonyD: Try this exercise... in front of a mirror start first by whispering and then increasing the voice tone until you get to a regular calm voice saying "there are cases in which macros are superior to templates". Just keep exercising until you're comfortable. This exercise should be helpful to get past your apparent macrophobia. It may also help learning about other tools for metaprogramming (e.g. Lisp macros) to be able to realize that templates (and more specifically the C++ incarnation) are not the silver bullet. One day you may even realize how an ugly hack really boost.spirit is.

Comment: :-)  I'm not even saying templates are superior to macros for this - just asking why you'd made the assertion I first quoted above, making sure I wasn't missing something.  All good.  And I like spirit, ugly hack or not!

Comment: @TonyD: generating code that depends on a parametric **name** is impossible with templates, and in the answer I'm generating code that accepts `+` as parameter (i.e. the operator name, used in two contexts: predefined `+` and `MyValue::operator +`). Templates can operate on types, on other templates and on a very limited subset of values (like numbers, member pointers). There's no way to generate code like `this->foo = foo;`  being passed the name `foo`, let alone composing new names like `m_foo` given `foo`. The "syntax level" is completely unreachable by C++ templates.

Comment: Well, I guess you wrote that with the particular type of "generation" you had in mind, but for those reading the answer without any particular expectations, the assertion is made before macros are mentioned and "this kind of code generation" reads as a more general denial of the ability of templates to "generate" support code for operators, which is untrue as a "mixin" approach is functional.  Anyway, this is undoubtedly as boring for you as it is for me, and readers will by now know both macros and templates are possibilities and can make up their own minds.  Cheers.